# TypeORM Postgres "deadlock detected, process waits for sharelock

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using a NestJS app which is making use of TypeORM and postgres database. For a few days now I keep getting errors that slow down the app performance drastically and I dont really know what that means or how to fix it. The error log is outputting this

```js
nftapi_1    | BalanceService saveAssets for 0x42e0ab4619C7Be98F7C9cd7B57Ba02362AD79459 QueryFailedError: deadlock detected
nftapi_1    |     at QueryFailedError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/app/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
nftapi_1    |     at new QueryFailedError (/app/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
nftapi_1    |     at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/app/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:263:19)
nftapi_1    |     at step (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
nftapi_1    |     at Object.throw (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
nftapi_1    |     at rejected (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:69)
nftapi_1    |     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
nftapi_1    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
nftapi_1    |   query: 'UPDATE "balance" SET "value" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "id" IN ($3) RETURNING "updated_at"',
nftapi_1    |   parameters: [ 0.08181107967456633, 2022-03-13T16:48:39.614Z, 2 ],
nftapi_1    |   driverError: error: deadlock detected
nftapi_1    |       at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
nftapi_1    |       at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
nftapi_1    |       at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
nftapi_1    |       at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
nftapi_1    |       at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
nftapi_1    |       at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
nftapi_1    |       at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
nftapi_1    |       at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
nftapi_1    |       at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
nftapi_1    |     length: 324,
nftapi_1    |     severity: 'ERROR',
nftapi_1    |     code: '40P01',
nftapi_1    |     detail: 'Process 155 waits for ShareLock on transaction 739100; blocked by process 145.\n' +
nftapi_1    |       'Process 145 waits for ShareLock on transaction 739099; blocked by process 155.',
nftapi_1    |     hint: 'See server log for query details.',
nftapi_1    |     position: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     internalPosition: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     internalQuery: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     where: 'while updating tuple (0,11) in relation "balance"',
nftapi_1    |     schema: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     table: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     column: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     dataType: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     constraint: undefined,
nftapi_1    |     file: 'deadlock.c',
nftapi_1    |     line: '1148',
nftapi_1    |     routine: 'DeadLockReport'
nftapi_1    |   },
nftapi_1    |   length: 324,
nftapi_1    |   severity: 'ERROR',
nftapi_1    |   code: '40P01',
nftapi_1    |   detail: 'Process 155 waits for ShareLock on transaction 739100; blocked by process 145.\n' +
nftapi_1    |     'Process 145 waits for ShareLock on transaction 739099; blocked by process 155.',
nftapi_1    |   hint: 'See server log for query details.',
nftapi_1    |   position: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   internalPosition: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   internalQuery: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   where: 'while updating tuple (0,11) in relation "balance"',
nftapi_1    |   schema: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   table: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   column: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   dataType: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   constraint: undefined,
nftapi_1    |   file: 'deadlock.c',
nftapi_1    |   line: '1148',
nftapi_1    |   routine: 'DeadLockReport'
nftapi_1    | }
```

These are the 2 functions used in the balance.service.ts file

```js
  private async updateEthBalance(account: Account): Promise<Account> {
    try {
      const balanceRepo = await getRepository(Balance);
      const wallets = account.wallets;

      if (wallets.length < 1) return;

      for (let i = 0; i < wallets.length; i++) {
        const wETH_wei = await this.openseaService.getSeaPort(wallets[i]).getTokenBalance({
          accountAddress: wallets[i].address,
          tokenAddress: WETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS,
        });
        const eth_wei = await this.web3.eth.getBalance(wallets[i].address);

        const formatted_weth = parseFloat(
          Web3.utils.fromWei(wETH_wei.toString(), 'ether'),
        );
        const formatted_eth = parseFloat(
          Web3.utils.fromWei(eth_wei.toString(), 'ether'),
        );

        const ethBalance = wallets[i].balances.find(b => b.symbol === "ETH");
        const wethBalance = wallets[i].balances.find(b => b.symbol === "wETH");
        //update values of balance entities
        ethBalance.value = formatted_eth;
        wethBalance.value = formatted_weth;

        await getRepository(Wallet).save(wallets[i])
      }

      return await getRepository(Account).save(account);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('BalanceService updateBalance', error);
    }
  }

  /**
   * save assets for specific wallet into database
   * @param wallet
   * @param assets
   * @private
   */
  private async saveAssets(wallet: Wallet, assets: any[]): Promise<Wallet> {
    try {
      wallet.assets = assets;
      return await this.walletRepository.save(wallet);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`BalanceService saveAssets for ${wallet.address}`, error);
    }
  }
```

How can I find out the cause for this? I am totally clueless, is there something I can do to narrow down these errors and fix it?